# Loading image from database to recyclerview using picasso

Tags: android

I have images which are saved in my local database i want to display them in my recylerview but if i add those image directly to imageview in my bindholder recyclerview scroll gets lag. So read an article to use picasso.But facing an issue, image is not getting loaded in imageview. Here is my code

```
String thumb = userData.getPhotoThumb();
if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(thumb)) {  Picasso.with(mContext).load(thumb).into(viewHolder.chatsListItemBinding.ivContactImage);}
```

Comment: See your Error Logs.

Comment: What exception are you getting with this code?

Comment: Is the variable `thumb` a path to an image? Does your app have access to this path? What code do you have in onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: could you please paste your logs here

Comment: show us the full code,adapter

Comment: @MayankPandya i got illegalstateexception:Unrecognize type of request

Answer (score 1):

Try to print `stackTrace` of an `exception` while loading image using `Picasso`

```
String thumb = userData.getPhotoThumb();
if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(thumb)) {
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    builder.build().load(thumb).into(viewHolder.chatsListItemBinding.ivContactImage);
}
```

I'm sure you'll figure out, what is going wrong with your code.

For more info [Picasso Official](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks wizard i found illegalstateexception:Unrecognize type of request

Comment: Alright, there must be a problem with `File Uri` if you are loading images from local storage!

Comment: actually i have encode the bitmap to string and save that encoded string to database  and trying to load it as bitmap

Comment: If you have bitmap, there is no need to use `Picasso`

Comment: As I have seen, there is no such imageLoader who loads bitmap directly to `imageview` you have to write your own logic or switch to `Uri` or `web urls`, Storing weburl is good because imageloaders are pretty efficient in the terms of memory as well as caching 'em

Comment: cant use the web urls as my app is a chat app where user have to put their profile picture

Comment: In that case you have to use `fileUri`, just like typical chat app does. You might wanna see the funda of `contentProvider` in android